# Return Boolean from a method

Tags: c#, object, boolean

I am making a save option in my program that saves the changes to a file.  I am using this code to save and get a `MessageBox` to show the result of the process I am getting an error on this line "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

```
     SaveFileCheck = StockHandler.SaveChangesToFile();
```

this is my code

```
    private void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        bool SaveFileCheck = false;
        var result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to Save the changes ?", "My   Application",
      MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
        if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
        {           

                 SaveFileCheck = StockHandler.SaveChangesToFile();
                 if (SaveFileCheck)
                 {
                     MessageBox.Show("The process was a success");
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     MessageBox.Show("The process failed please make sure that the file is not been       used and try again");
                 } 

            //Save the file back


        }
    }
}
}

    public bool SaveChangesToFile() 
    {
        try
        {
            if (FileName != null)
            {
                using (StreamWriter Write = new StreamWriter(FileName, false))
                {
                    foreach (Stock s in FileStockList)
                    {
                        Write.Write(s.ToString() + "\r\n");

                    }

                }
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }

        }
        catch(IOException ex) 
        {
            return false;
            throw new ArgumentException("something went wrong an error" + ex + "is been cought");

        }
        return true;


    }
```

Comment: `StockHandler` must be `null`; are you sure you're instantiating it? (like `StockHandler = new StockHandler()`)

Comment: `StockHandler` is `null`, assign a class instance to it before calling a method on it

Comment: What line in the `SaveChangesToFile` is throwing the exception? Is it `foreach (Stock s in FileStockList)`? If that is the case, then `FileStockList` is still `null` - you forgot to create it.

Comment: What is FileStockList and where is it initialized ?

Comment: Show us the first few lines of code for `StockHandler`.

Comment: i edited the code the stockhandler is instance of stockhelper which the savechangestofile method is thier

Comment: You need to include the code that shows how you're instantiating all of these classes.

Comment: So does it work now that you've edited the code in your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`StockHandler` is null.

If `StockHandler` is not a `static` class, you need to create an instance of it before you can call methods on it:

```
var handler = new StockHandler();
SaveFileCheck = handler.SaveChangesToFile();
```

Or, if `StockHandler` is a member variable:

```
StockHandler = new // something
```

Comment: i edited the code the stockhandler is instance of stockhelper which the savechangestofile method is thier

Answer (score 2):

You haven't shown what `StockHandler` is, or where you're getting it from - but it looks like it's null. You'll need it to be a reference to a valid object. There's not a lot more we can say just from the code you've given.

Note that this has *nothing* to do with a method returning a `bool`.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that `StockHandler` is null, or something in the `SaveChangesToFile` method is null or invalid.

**EDIT**

See here:

```
private StockHelper StockHandler;
StockHandler.SaveChangesToFile(); // = bang :(
```

You need to initialize the `StockHelper` instance:

```
private StockHelper StockHandler = new StockHelper();
StockHandler.SaveChangesToFile(); // = okay :)
```

I'm assuming that this code doesn't compile, which probably means that `StockHandler` is null. Otherwise, the error would likely be pointing to the `SaveChangesToFile` method.

Secondly, you either need to swallow exceptions in the `SaveChangesToFile()` method (not advisable), or you need to remove the return statement and throw the exception. If you do decide to throw an exception, it should definitely not be an `ArgumentException`, as it has nothing to do with arguments supplied to the method (or lack thereof).

Answer (score 0):

What is stockhandler -- your SaveChangesToFile method is an instance method -- so have you instantiated a variable 'StockHandler' to an instance of whatever class contains the method SaveChangesToFile();